# How to change window frame size without change its location

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

```
self.view.window?.frame.size.width = 430
self.view.window?.frame.size.height = 310
```

The `height` and `width` are `read-only`, so seems the only way to change the dimension of a `frame` is to re-assign an NSRect to it using code below,

```
self.view.window?.setFrame(NSMakeRect(0, 0, 430, 310), display: true, animate: true)
```

Is there a way to change window frame size without change its location?

Comment: Get the frame of the window, change the size and set the frame. Or use `setContentSize(_:)`.

Comment: frame.height is read-only but frame.size.height is read-write property

Comment: The window origin is in the bottom left corner. When you say "without change it's location" you probably mean that you want the top left corner to remain in place rather than the bottom left. So when you change the frame, you need to adjust the origin y coordinate accordingly. Example: if you add 100 pixel to the windows height, you need to subtract 100 pixel from the windows origin.y coordinate to make it "stay in place".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `origin` of the original `frame` and make a new `NSRect` with a different size.

Something like this for instance:

```
func resizeFrame(newWidth: CGFloat, newHeight: CGFloat) {
    if let originalFrame = view.window?.frame {
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        view.window?.setFrame(NSRect(origin: originalFrame.origin, size: newSize), display: true, animate: true)
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
resizeFrame(newWidth: 430, newHeight: 310)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

As Gerd K said, the y coordinate needs to be adjusted. To save others time, here is that calculation fashioned after pbodsk's example:

```
func resizeFrame(newWidth: CGFloat, newHeight: CGFloat) {

    if let originalFrame = view.window?.frame {
        let newY = originalFrame.origin.y + originalFrame.size.height - newHeight
        view.window?.setFrame(NSRect(x: originalFrame.origin.x, y: newY, width: newWidth, height: newHeight), display: true, animate: true)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
resizeFrame(newWidth: 430, newHeight: 310)
```